# ConstraintLayout: Could adding unnecessary constraints decrease performance?

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Imagine following (made up) scenario:

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with height set to `wrap_content` containing two `TextViews` and all the `ConstraintLayout` does is to arrange them vertically (basically act like a vertical LinearLayout):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_view"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Would it in any way impact performance if I additionally constrained the first `View` to the second one through `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/second_view"`?

So my precise question is: In this scenario where the additional constraint wouldn't make any difference in terms of arrangement of the layout, would it be better to add the additional constraint, remove the additional constraint or does it not matter at all?

Comment: If you don't need the constraint then don't add it not because of performance reasons but for maintainability. I will say that you should not use `match_parent` on direct children of _ConstraintLayout_ but use `0dp` with the appropriate constraints to the parent.

Comment: Ah, that is good to know, I didn't know it made a difference! Thanks.